# Prototypechain between Class object and constructor function

Tags: javascript

I want make a prototypechain between my class object and constructor function. Currently I am using Object.create() for it but Im getting the read-only error, It only works if I use Constructor function instead of class to inherites prototype of other object but why?

My code:

```
const Car = function (make, speed) {
  this.make = make;
  this.speed = speed;
};

Car.prototype.accelerate = function () {
  this.speed += 10;
};

const EV = class {
  constructor(make, speed, charge) {
    Car.call(this, make, speed);
    this.charge = charge;
  }
};

// Link to prototype
EV.prototype = Object.create(Car.prototype);  // Uncaught TypeError: "prototype" is read-only
```

Comment: Because the prototype of a `class` is read-only. Were you looking for `class EV extends Car {` (~ `const EV = class extends Car {`) as an answer, or why it’s read-only for classes, or…? You should use `super` instead of `Car.call`, by the way.

Comment: The whole point of [`class` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) is that you don't have to play games with the `prototype` property of constructor functions anymore in the vast majority of cases. What is the goal that requires your doing so here? The code shown is better expressed with [simple method definitions and `extends`](https://pastebin.com/tNmBXbnn). Is there more to it?

Comment: (Sorry, I missed out the `extends Car` on that pastebin link: https://pastebin.com/pxDADqEA)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Definitely you wouldn't want to overwrite your class' prototype since it COULD contains the class' methods.

But you can set a prototype's prototype, but as was mentioned in the comments you'd better use `extends`. On the other hand sometimes it's needed/useful to inject other prototypes into a prototype chain so that's it:

```js
'use strict';

const Car = function (make, speed) {
  this.make = make;
  this.speed = speed;
};

Car.prototype.accelerate = function () {
  this.speed += 10;
};

const EV = class {
  constructor(make, speed, charge) {
    Car.call(this, make, speed);
    this.charge = charge;
  }
};

// Link to prototype
Object.setPrototypeOf(EV.prototype, Object.create(Car.prototype));  // Uncaught TypeError: "prototype" is read-only 

const ev = new EV('Toyota', 100, () => console.log('charged'));
ev.accelerate();
console.log('speed:', ev.speed);
```